# Is it possible to rotate portion of still image in swift (making car tire spin)

Tags: swift, animation

I have a car image and I wanted just the rear wheels to spin when the image is pressed. Is it possible to select a portion of the image to animate? I was thinking of uploading 2 images, the car and wheel, since the car does not need to move yet. I was hoping there was a cleaner way to do this. 
Any suggestions would be great thanks !

Comment: Hi, Try to use CGImageCreateWithImageInRect to do the animation. Although I don't find uploading two images as un-clean way. Its the other way around. Instead of doing processing in your app to extract the wheels. Just provide the app with the necessary images

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Add following extension :**  (*If you don't know ->[What is Extension?](https://learnappmaking.com/swift-extensions-how-to/)   [How to Add Extension?](http://swiftdeveloperblog.com/code-examples/class-extension-example-swift/) click question hyperlink.*)

```
extension UIView {
    func rotate360Degrees(duration: CFTimeInterval = 2) {
        let rotateAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.rotation")
        rotateAnimation.fromValue = 0.0
        rotateAnimation.toValue = CGFloat(Double.pi * 2)
        rotateAnimation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
        rotateAnimation.duration = duration
        rotateAnimation.repeatCount=Float.infinity
        self.layer.add(rotateAnimation, forKey: nil)
    }
}
```

**Usage :**

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
       carFirstWheelImage.rotate360Degrees()
       carSecondWheelImage.rotate360Degrees() // you can change the time interval to change speed
}
```

**Suggestion:**
You can also change the Background with multiple image changing. That will give your car a running animation look. That will make your story more awesome !